# How can I connect to OS X 10.6 from a Windows server 2008 using VNC over the internet?

Tags: mac

I have an apple Mac-mini 10.6 and 10.7 with me. when i am trying to connect Mac-mini from Windows server 2008 using vnc server over the internet from my windows machine using http://ipaddress-of Mac:5800/, the connection is not set up.

Please anyone help on this.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the option in System Preferences? You set it in Sharing -> Screen Sharing, this enables the VNC server under OS X and opens the port for it.

Comment: Thanks for replying smith. I have enabled the options for screen sharing but unfortunately it didn't works and moreover i didn't found any ways to open the port(i.e 5800) in mac. could you please help me what to do next?

Comment: It should be port 5900 rather than 5800, that might be catching you out.

Comment: Sorry for being so late but port 5900 is already open on mac and assigned to vnc but still the connection is not possible. When i am trying to connect mac using http://ip-address:5900/ then IE browser displays RFB 003.889 written on top. Apeart from that it shows nothing. Please help me as this is a major blocker in my project.

Comment: Firewall is disabled on mac 10.6 and it is allowing all incoming connection but the problem still persist.

Comment: How are you trying to connect? Essentially from a Windows machine you need a vnc client pointed at the ip address. If you're doing it from outside the network the Mac is on you'll need an ip address for the network or a dynamic domain name.

Comment: Both of my machine i.e Windows server 2008 r2 and Mac 10.6 are on same network and i am trying to connect mac 10.6 from windows machine using IE browser by typing http://ip-address of mac machine:5800/. vnc is installed on windows and both machine have java SE 1.6 installed.

Comment: Right, the web browser thing doesn't work everytime on Windows. Install a client on the Windows machine [TightVNC for example](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php). You should get access from there.

Comment: Thanks for reply Nicholas but my project requirement is to access mac machine using browser. This requirement really made me mad. Actually, the connection using vncviewer.exe is working perfectly but we have to achieve it using browser. Please help

Comment: Ah, then you'll have to dig around for a Java browser-based VNC client, the vnc:// works on OS X by dumping it out of the web browser to a dedicated application.

Comment: When i am trying to connect Windows machine from mac using safari by typing the url as http://ipaddress of windows machine:5800/ then connection become possible and we can access the windows machine from mac browser i.e safari but the reverse operation from windows to mac using browser is not working.

Comment: Actually when you run it on OS X you're seeing it launch OS Xs built in VNC client, not a browser based one.

Comment: Yeah that's true. but i wonder why this is not happening in IE browser. Should it need any setting on windows machine or i am missing on something important.

Comment: OS X/Safari implements a URL scheme that tells the OS that a URL with vnc:// is to be redirected to the VNC application, Windows does a similar thing with ftp://. [look at this Microsoft article on URL schemes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx) it should give you some tips.

Comment: if i tried to access other windows machine from my windows server 2008 r2 using IE browser the connection is established correctly. the only problem i am facing is that mac machine is not getting accessed.

Comment: I think that uses RDP not VNC. This is getting a bit long now, but the basic answer is you either need to setup a url scheme on the Windows machine to open VNC, or install a browser based VNC client.

Comment: No Nicholas that is not RDP because if we use IE browser then it ask for VNC Authentication Password